# Я получаю не тот вывод, что нужно при импортировании файлов (с родительским и дочерним классом) Может кто-то знает как это исправить?

Tags: python, импорт

Всем привет, у меня возникла проблема с выводом информации, я получаю не тот вывод, что нужно и не могу это решить можете, пожалуйста, помочь

я имею главный файл под названием `t1`

```
lst = [[0, 1, 5], [2, 3, 6], [4, 5, 8], [0, 3, 2]]

if __name__ == '__main__':
   import t2
   for n in range(0, len(lst)):
      a = t2.Employee(lst[n][0], lst[n][1])
      a.determine()
```

также родительский класс `t2`

```
from t1 import lst

class Employee:
   def __init__(self, kod, PIP):
      self.kod = kod
      self.PIP = PIP

   def determine(self):
      for i in lst:
         if i[0] == 0:
            import t3
            p = t3.Prog(self.kod, self.PIP)
            p.calculateSalary()
         elif i[0] == 2:
            import t4
            j = t4.last(self.kod, self.PIP)
            j.calculateSalary()
```

и два дочерних класса `t3`

```
from t2 import Employee
class Prog(Employee):

    def __init__(self, kod, PIP):
      super().__init__(kod, PIP)

    def calculateSalary(self):
       if self.PIP == 5:
          s = self.kod + self.PIP
          print(s)
       elif self.PIP == 2:
          s = self.kod + self.PIP
          print(s)
```

и `t4`

```
  from t2 import Employee
  class last(Employee):

     def __init__(self, kod, PIP):
        super().__init__(kod, PIP)

     def calculateSalary(self):
        if self.PIP == 6:
           s = self.kod + self.PIP
           print(s)
```

Я вроде бы разобралась с проблемой циклического импорта.(но что-то мне подсказывает что все-таки проблема все же из for). Мне нужно получить такой вывод

```
6
9
5
```

я получаю такой вывод

```
   6
   6
   9
   5
   5
```

Я не очень понимаю, почему так получается. Возможно, кто-то знает как это исправить. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: 100%, что не в импорте:-)

Comment: @Сергей ошибка все же у for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так у вас два цикла по `lst`:

- в основном файле `t1`
- в `Employee.determine`

Я прошёл глазами несколько первых итераций - фактический вывод соответствует коду, всё работает как закодировано.

По максимуму там могло вообще 16 чисел напечататься, потому что это цикл в цикле 4*4 = 16, но у вас не все ветки кода делают печать, поэтому печатается меньше.

Видимо, какой-то из этих циклов лишний, но понять какой именно, не зная постановку задачи, затруднительно.

Comment: Условие задачи: тот список должен быть списком работников с инициалами, зарплатой и работой, которую он делает, в зависимости от типа (определяемого в родительском классе) и процентом который нужно вычесть из их зарплаты (в дочернем классе).На вывод должен пойти зарплата, которую они получат на руки, но этот код я решила немного упростить

Comment: То есть я должен сделать элементы списка аргументами класса, чтобы их дальше использовать.То есть для этого я использую первый. А второй для определения типа работника

Comment: @st040506 Но класс `Employee` при инициализации уже получил всю нужную информацию, зачем ещё один цикл? В `self.kod` и `self.PIP` лежит всё, что нужно, по идее.

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста еще раз на задание, я его исправила, в аргумент класса мне не нужно передавать один объект, и поэтому мне его нужно еще раз импортировать из списка в Employee

Comment: Извините, что не до конца сформулировала свою задачу

Comment: И всё же я не понимаю, зачем вам второй цикл